# Size of assosiation in Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, associations, criteria, fetch

I've faced with a problem when querying with Hibernate Criteria in Grails.

Take a look:

```
def visitors = Client.withCriteria{
          visits{
             use ( TimeCategory ) {between('date',date,date+1.month-1)}
          }
          sizeGe("visits",params.from)
          sizeLe("visits",params.to)
          fetchMode("visits", FM.JOIN)
};
```

I need only those clients, which has **number of visits** in month between **from** and **to** bounds.

But now **size*** restrictions is being applied to all visits.  So if client has one visit in this month, and visit in previous month. And if I set **from=2**, this client will be in result. But it should not be there.

//UPD:
the thing as that **sizeGe** and **sizeLe** restrictions work not as I expect.

From my point of view they should be applied after **between** restriction, but they not.

For example:

```
def client = new Client();

client.visits.add(new Visit(date:'2010-03-16'));
client.visits.add(new Visit(date:'2010-05-16'));
client.visits.add(new Visit(date:'2010-05-17'));
client.save();
```

And then I want if:

- date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM','2010-05')
- params.from=2

criteria should return this client, and if

- params.from = 3

not return;
But it returns, because **sizeGe** is being applied to **all** visits, no matter which date it has.

// END UPD.

Let me know if smth still isn't clear.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Vova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a having clause to do this and I found on [issue open in Hibernate's Jira](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1043) to add support for this.

Meanwhile you should use HQL and write the query by hand, [see this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping). If you don't need to change the query's restrictions based on some selected fields you should I always go with HQL, it can be cached.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Felipe.

Also, I've choose to use sqlRestriction. Of course, it has some portability issues but it works:

```
def visitors = c.listDistinct{
        use(TimeCategory){
                visits{

                    between('date',date,date+1.month-1)
                }

                sqlRestriction(
                        """(
                            select count(*)
                                  from visit v
                            where
                                v.visitor_id={alias}.id
                                and v.date between 
                                      '${date.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}' 
                                      and '${(date+1.month-1).format("yyyy-MM-dd")}'
                            )
                            between ${params.from} and ${params.to}"""
                )
            }
    }
```

Thanks, Vova.